# Emgu.CV.CvInvoke exception on PCs without Visual Studio installations

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2012, emgucv

I have an application which works with EmguCV.

I am getting the error while running the executable in some particular PCs.

The computer with visual studio installed will work fine and the one which does not have VS , gives the error on `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke` exception.

Please let me know What will be the best solution for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i figured out my problem and i have resolved it at the end of the day by installing Microsoft C++  redistributable framework 2012. 
If You have added all dll's and still if you are getting the error , just install the correct version , for me https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the VCRT DLLs (msvcr120.dll, msvcp120.dll) to the location of the executable:

The VCRT DLLs are available in x86 and x64 folders.

Refer to this [link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.) for official documentation.

Comment: Hi @abhishek , I am Using Emgu (emgucv-windesktop 3.1.0.2504)  and the same exe will run in all PC's which has VS2013 , but I have another PC which has.NET framework(VS not installed) but the same exe with all dlls not working. emgu.cv.Cvinvoke error . I think this will be because of .net framework, Can you please let me know about it.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Kindly check if it works.

Comment: Hi , I have checked with your solution , i am still getting the same problem ,if i installed Visual studio , it will not give the error , what will be the cause , my application framework is 4.5.1

Comment: Hi , I got the result , Install c++ redistributable framework ,based on your  .NET project. It may help to someone

Comment: Why don't you post an answer then